# Electrical Disconnects for condensing unit

Tags: hvac, nec

What year did the NEC code require electrical disconnects to be installed at HVAC condensing unit?

Comment: When was you unit installed? Where are you located?

Comment: And why are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

The following is from the 1999 NEC (my 1990 NEC hard copy has the same wording in the same location) so it has been there a long long time:

> 440-14. Location. Disconnecting means shall be located within sight from and readily accessible from the air-conditioning or refrigerating equipment. The disconnecting means shall be permitted to be installed on or within the air-conditioning or refrigerating equipment.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: I'd guess that it's been in there since the addition of article 440, which was likely quite a long time ago.

Comment: @Tester101 I would suspect that is the case. I searched a little on the internet but I can't find any really old copies of the code like 50's, 60's, etc. in PDF form. It probably dates from when residential air conditioning became affordable.